# Direct2D Memory overuse when resizing windows

Tags: c++, memory, resize, direct2d

I've recently started to use Direct2D, found out some strange behaviour when resizing the window: memory use skyrocket, and in the end I get some "out of memory error". Here is the layout of my code :

```
// Nothing special in there
int wWinMain(...)
{
    // Window creation, ressource allocation, message loop.
}
```

Then the windowProc

```
// Nothing special in there either
case WM_PAINT :
    if(myObject->paint()) {
        ValidateRect(myObject->rect());
        return 0;
     }
    else return DefWindowProc(...);
default :
    return DefWindowProc(...);
```

For the paint method I just use

```
// Check the ressources
checkRessources();

mRenderTarget->BeginDraw();

mRenderTarget->EndDraw();

// Check for errors
checkForError();
```

There's nothing else than that. Everything compiles fine, the window is displated. Then I take the resizing handle, and start shaking it, which causes the my window to be constantly resized and repainted. After some 20s shaking it, the memory starts begin overused (some 200Mo are used every seconds) until it reaches the full capacity of my computer RAM...

I looked for the origin of such a behaviour and found out that it was cause solely by the

```
BeginDraw();
EndDraw();
```

part. I removed all the painting done, stoppped handling all messages but WM_PAINT. Still... (And I also turned of debugging).

Then I checked some other code, namely the [Direct2D Hello World Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317124%28VS.85%29.aspx). Shaked the window resize handle. And get exactly the same memory overuse....

So. I don't know what causes that. Is it a Direct2D bug? My graphic card driver? Does any one experience the same phenomena ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get that behavior. The memory use does increase but only up to about 2mb, then it stops increasing.

There's one part about your question that seems like contradiction:

> I looked for the origin of such a behaviour and found out that it was cause solely by the
>
> BeginDraw();
>
> EndDraw();
>
> part. I removed all the painting done, stoppped handling all messages but WM_PAINT. Still... (And I also turned of debugging).

So it's caused by the BeginDraw/EndDraw calls, but then you remove them and the problem persists?

EDIT: to see the description of a _com_error exception, wrap all your code in wWinMain in a try/catch block, like this:

```
int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (const _com_error& e)
    { // <-- Put a breakpoint at this line and then inspect the "e" variable in the Locals window in the debugger

        // Or use this:
        ::MessageBoxW(nullptr, e.ErrorMessage(), L"Error", MB_ICONSTOP);
    }
}
```

Comment: No. When I remove them I don't get that problem anymore.

Comment: OK. Well anyway I don't get that problem on my PC so you might want to try it on another PC to see if it's something with your code or something weird with the PC you're currently testing it on.

Comment: I'll try that. But anyway, I haven't the slightest why this is happening. My code does nothing (i.e. don't allocate resources, doesn't performs any painting and don't handle any Window Message in the `WindowProc`). Could the `CreateHwndRenderTarget` be the source of that ? (I'm using default values).

Comment: Also, when I check with the task manager, the memory used by my program (or the hello world sample) doesn't increase, but the memory that is available on my computer decreases until 0.Then I get some `_com_error_` (that I don't know how to use because the window API is new to me...)

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to obtain information from a _com_error exception, though it's most likely an out-of-memory exception (HRESULT E_OUT_OF_MEMORY).

Comment: I'll try that, but I agree, I'm pretty sure that it's a out-of-memory. But why (the h***) would there be (huge - because my whole computer runs out) memory allocation in a `BeginDraw()` ?

Comment: One question: do you call GDI's ::BeginPaint and ::EndPaint before and after ID2D1RenderTarget::BeginDraw and ID2D1RenderTarget::EndDraw, respectively? I'm not sure it has to do with the problem, but I don't see it in the code you posted.

Comment: Is there any need to call GDI `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint`? I'm using the potential of Direct2D. I don't want my code to have anything to do with GDI at all! ... So I never call the GDI function. Should I tray to wrap the Direct2D call within the GDI `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint`

Comment: You're absolutely right, there's no need for BeginPaint/EndPaint. I once saw a sample that used them so I thought they were necessary, but now I realized they're not necessary.

Comment: It seems that the driver caused that. Now they're brand new, and... Well I don't have this problem.